# How to restore scroll postition while navigating between client side routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My setup is similar to following

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={Home} />
        <Route path='/blog' render={Blog} />
        <Route path='/about' render={About} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In `NavBar`, I have setup links to all these routes using `<NavLink>`.

I am perfectly able to navigate between the routes but scroll position is not restored.

As per react-router documentation, browser should be able to restore scroll position. But it only work when navigation is done using either `browser back button` or `history.goBack()` . However, it isn't ideal for current scenario, as nav links are always visible and its not practical to navigate between different routes using back.

My take is that `<Link>` is pushing new path to history and browser treats it as new page. So any workaround or standard solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue per se because from UX perspective you are not expected to have a scroll position restored when clicking on link, only when using the back button.